# jQuery where INPUT is checked

Tags: jquery, html

I have this jQuery which gives me a set of INPUT items.

```
var list = $("input[name*='popSearch']")
```

How would I modify it to only return those where the INPUT element is checked ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first  [docs.jquery.com](http://docs.jquery.com) is a fanstastic resource,

however to your request this should work,

```
var list = $("input[name*='popSearch'] :checked")
```

Comment: This shouldn't work, it's looking for a `:checked` element *inside* the input. But it's the input itself that can be checked. Dan has it right, without the space.

Answer (score 3):

`var list = $("input[name*='popSearch']:checked");`

See the [documentation on selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors).

Answer (score 3):

I think this should do it:

```
var list = $("input[name*='popSearch']:checked")
```